Quantum circuit for the symmetry operator
I am interested in building a quantum circuit for the symmetry operator with respect to the
state $|0^n\rangle$. The quantum register is then composed of $n$ qubits.
This symmetry operator $\hat{S}$ can be primarily defined on the computational basis :
\begin{equation}
\hat{S}|x\rangle = \begin{cases}
 |x\rangle  &\text{if} \;|x\rangle = |0^n\rangle\\
 -|x\rangle  &\text{if} \;\langle x |0^n\rangle = 0
\end{cases} \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
A generic expression of $\hat{S}$ is :
\begin{equation}
\hat{S} = 2 |0^n\rangle\langle 0^n | -I = 
 \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & & \vdots\\
\vdots &  & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & -1
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
which conforms to (1).
For 2 qubits, it comes down to :
\begin{equation}
\hat{S} = 
 \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right] = |0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes Z - |1\rangle\langle 1| \otimes I
\end{equation}
In view that :
\begin{equation}
|0\rangle\langle 0| = \frac{I+Z}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad |1\rangle\langle 1| = \frac{I-Z}{2}
\end{equation}
One can transform further $\hat{S}$ :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hat{S} &=   \frac{I+Z}{2} \otimes Z - \frac{I-Z}{2} \otimes I \\
        &= \frac{1}{2} (I\otimes Z + Z\otimes Z - I + Z\otimes I )\\
        &= \frac{1}{2} (Z_2 + Z_1 Z_2 - I + Z_1)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where I used : $Z_1 = Z\otimes I$ and $Z_2 = I\otimes Z$, that $Z_i$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix but which does something only on $i^{th}$ qubit.
Finally, with a little of guess (e.g. apply $\hat{S}$ to the computational basis) one can put
$\hat{S}$ in the form :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hat{S} &= \frac{1}{2} (Z_2 + Z_1 Z_2 - I + Z_1) \\
        &=\frac{1}{2} (I - Z_1 Z_2 + Z_2 + Z_1)Z_1 Z_2\\
   &= \biggl[\frac{I+Z}{2} \otimes I + \frac{I-Z}{2} \otimes Z\biggr]Z_1 Z_2\\
   &= \biggl[|0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle 1| \otimes Z\biggr]Z_1 Z_2\\
   &= C_Z Z_1 Z_2 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So the quantum circuit is :

one $Z$ gate on each qubit,
a controlled $Z$ gate, controlled by first qubit.

I wonder if this can be generalized for the case of $n>2$ qubits ? and what is the depth of a quantum circuit for $n$ qubits ?

If this is a standalone gate and don't care about the global phase in $-\hat{S}$, then we can simply do a multi-controlled $Z$, controlled on the all $|0\rangle$ state. But we can also implement $\hat{S}$ directly, with some work.
Lets start with why $CZ_{1,2} Z_1 Z_2$ works here. All of these gates commute, so we can think of what each of them are doing independently to some computational basis state. Applying $Z$'s to all qubits gives it adds a phase for all the states with a single $1$. The other states ($|00\rangle$, $|11\rangle$) are unchanged. The $CZ$ applies a phase to $|11\rangle$, which is the state with 2 $1$'s.
We can extend that idea to 3 qubits. Apply 0-controlled $Z$'s to all the qubits to apply a phase to states with weight 1, single-controlled $Z$'s to all the pairs to apply a phase to all the states with weight 2, and a doubly controlled $Z$.

In general, the map can be implemented by making a $Z$ controlled on every computational state where the $1$'s are. Simply by enumerating all the bitstrings, example for 4 qubits:


I'm not sure how to directly generalise the construction you give for n=2 to n>2, sorry.
You can note, however, that this gate is equivalent up to a global phase to a Grover oracle that marks the all zero state.
The following math overflow answer by Craig Gidney concerns how to construct Grover oracles: https://mathoverflow.net/a/204553.
In short, you could create a gate equivalent to the one you are after, up to a global phase of $-1$, by implementing a controlled-$Z$ gate with controls on every qubit - this applies a $-1$ phase to the all 1 state - conjugated by a layer of $X$ gates on every qubit (which map the all 0 zero state to the all 1 state, so this gets the phase applied to it instead).
In other words, $\hat{S} \equiv X^{\otimes n}C^{n}(Z)X^{\otimes n}$.
As for the depth - this depends on what gates you have access to; if you only have access to say CNOTs or Toffolis (and single qubit gates), then you can construct a big $C^n(X)$ (which you could convert into the $C^n(Z)$ gate you need by conjugating with Hadamard on the target qubit) using $\mathcal{O}(n)$ gates, as shown again by Craig in this CS StackExchange answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/44292.
